# dojo order of execution

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to dojo and I am trying to assign a variable in a specific order. Here is an example:

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
    var myVar;

    request("helloworld.txt").then(
        function(text){
            myVar = text;
            alert(myVar);  //2nd alert to display and contains contents of helloworld.txt
        },
            function(error){
            console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
        }

    );

    alert(myVar); //1st alert to display and displays undefined
});
```

I need myVar to be assigned inside of  the ".then" function and then use it outside of that function. In other words, I need the 1st alert to contain the contents of helloworld.txt. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand callbacks and asynchronous code! These are absolutely fundamental concepts in Javascript, so you'll do yourself a big favor by reading up on it.

It has been explained far better than I could many many times, so I'll just leave you with some links (and a quick way to accomplish what you want).

- http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/
- http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Even if you don't read those links, here's what you have to keep in mind: **Just because line 10 comes before line 100 in your Javascript code, doesn't mean line 10 will run before line 100.**

Dojo's `request` function returns something called a "Promise". The promise allows you to say "Hey, in the future, after you're done with what I just told you to do, run this function!" (you do this with the `then` function, like you've done).

If you find this confusing, remember that promises are in many ways just a wrapper around the `onSuccess` or `onError` attributes you see in many other frameworks or scripts.

The great thing is that `then` also returns a new promise! So you can "chain" them together:

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
    var myVar;

    request(
        "helloworld.txt"
    ).then(
        function(text){
            myVar = text;
            alert("First alert! " + myVar); 
        },
        function(error){
            console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
        }
    ).then(
        function() {
            alert("Second alert! " + myVar);
        }
    );
});
```

Promises have other neat advantages as well, but I wont go into that here.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the info. So as I understand it, it is impossible to define a variable inside of a then function and use it any where outside of the request.